# How to use Google Cloud Client Library for Python to configure the gcloud project

Tags: python, gcloud, google-client, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

Hi I am trying to use the Google Cloud Client Library for Python to convert a shell script using the gcloud CLI to launch a container to python.  In searching through the documentation (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/), I have been unable to find functionality that would allow me to configure the gcloud project.  For example, for the command-line `gcloud config set project <project-name>`, I have not come across equivalent functionality with the Python client.  Is anyone aware of this functionality with the client library?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood your question but if you want to set Google CLI project property, you can use `subprocess` for this and verify with `google.auth`:

```
import subprocess
import google.auth


if __name__ == "__main__":
    project_id = 'my-project'
    subprocess.run(['gcloud', 'config', 'set', 'project', project_id, ])
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
    print(project_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't get your question right.

It is possible, let me just take the example of gcloud storage. When creating a Client instance you can provide a project name:

```
class gcloud.storage.client.Client(project=None, credentials=None, http=None)
```

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/storage-client.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) library and [gcloud cli tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) are not related. It is possible for gcloud-python library (or many other libraries) to use [application default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/auth/application-default/) set up gcloud cli tool, but any other gcloud settings are not exported.

If you wish to use those settings you can take advantage of [`--format`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) gcloud-cli flag:

```
gcloud config list --format=json
```

which will return json object of [all settings](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) which you can parse and use in your script, for example pass project setting to gcloud-python library.